# Simple MySQL tunnel without SSL or SSH?

Tags: port-forwarding, forwarding, tunneling, tunnel, stunnel

### What I have

I have a MySQL database that allows whitelisting only 2 individual IP addresses. No other access to that server except a MySQL username and password.

### What I need

I need to connect Google Looker Studio to that database, but it [requires whitelisting a whole /23 range](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7088031#firewal).

How do I connect them together? I also have a spare tiny VPS with root access and a public IPv4 address that I can use for this.

### What I tried

The idea was to:

1. whitelist the IP of that VPS with the database, and then
2. set up some kind of a tunnel between that VPS and the database
3. connect to a port on that VPS

I tried this:

- SSH tunnel came to mind first, but is only possible when an underlying SSH connection is involved, which Google Looker Studio won't do. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277017/tunnel-connection-to-mysql-without-ssh-access)
- `stunnel` errors out:

  > Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 54

  My `/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf`:

  ```
  ; It is recommended to drop root privileges if stunnel is started by root
  setuid = stunnel4
  setgid = stunnel4

  ; PID file is created inside the chroot jail (if enabled)
  pid = /var/run/stunnel/stunnel.pid

  ; Debugging stuff (may be useful for troubleshooting)
  foreground = yes
  debug = debug
  output = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log

  ; MySQL Tunnel
  [mysql-tunnel]
  client = yes
  accept = 33066
  connect = 1.2.3.4:3306
  ```

  I am connecting using MySQL Workbench to `my-vps:33066`.

Is there a better / simpler way? Please help

Comment: As per [your other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1145822/) if you want to relay TCP, use socat not stunnel

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Hi and thank you for your comment, please post it as an answer so I can accept it